# Renaming Multiple XML files using VBScript

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, xml-parsing

I've got a directory full of XML archives. 
Something like 400 XMLs, and I need to rename each one of them with data that is present on them, using VBScript.

I have done some code that functions, but still got problems:

**@EDIT** -> Solved. I found a "Replace" function. Thanks, Ekkehard!

- Some of the nodes' values that I use for renaming the file have illegal characters ("/", more precisely), what makes VBScript unable to save it, returning a "Path not found" error. How could I manage to change every "/" (if they exist in the present Operadora that is assumed in the variable) for each "Operadora" value before using it to rename the file? I would change it to "-".

Here is the code:

```
Dim Caminho
Dim FSO
Dim FLD
Dim fil
Dim nomeErrado
Dim nomeCerto
Dim xmlDoc
Dim OrganisationInfo, Operadora, recentDate, resultOperadora

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0") 'Msxml2.DOMDocument / Microsoft.XMLDOM   
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

Caminho = "C:\Users\f8057612\Desktop\Bancos\Script_Operadoras"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        'Create the instance of the FSO
Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(Caminho)                            'Set the folder you want to search. NOTE - some antivirus may not like this

For Each fil in FLD.Files
    If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(fil)) = "xml" Then
        xmlDoc.Load fil.Path
        nomeErrado = fil.Path

        If xmlDoc.ParseError = 0 Then

            For Each OrganisationInfo In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//OrganisationInfo/OrganisationName")
                Operadora = OrganisationInfo.Text
            Next

            resultOperadora = Replace(Operadora, "/", "-")

            nomeCerto = "IR21 - " & resultOperadora & " - " & ".xml"
            WScript.Echo "_" & nomeErrado & "_" & vbNewLine & "_" & nomeCerto & "_"

            FSO.MoveFile nomeErrado, nomeCerto

        End If
    End If
Next

Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Line 32 seems to be `End If`. Can you mark the line please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, please identify the problem/error un-equivocally: Error Number, Error Description, line (not by number, but by citing the source).

If 32 is the correct line number, then

```
FSO.MoveFile nomeErrado, nomeCerto
```

is to blame. The most like cause is: a file named nomeCerto already exists. One remedy could be: Check whether the target file exists, if yes, append a number to the name. Another: check whether your XPath fails (and Operadora is 're-used'), if so log the fact and don't rename the file.

**Update:**

I tried to come with a scenario causing .MoveFile to throw a "path not found error". As you loop over the .Files collection and use the files' .Path to specify the source of the .MoveFile, it's hard to see how the source path can't be found. Same holds for the target path: Whether you or the FSO's default specify where to move the file - if the action succeds for some files, surely the path of the nasty destinations should be found just as well.

My first move would be to get a list of some succeeding and some failing (source) files. Are there obvious pecularities of the bad ones - like funny letters (-> encoding) or attributes (-> permissions)?

Then I would display the contents of the variable nomeCerto (for the nasty files) using MsgBox and delimiters - e.g.

```
MsgBox "|" & nomeCerto & "|"
```

Perhaps Operadora contains material (whitespace, \, /, use your own imagination) that makes nomeCerto illegal.

Comment: I edited my post, sorry to forget that. It's a "path not found" error :/

Comment: I'm testing it here. There is no such file named "nomeCerto" in the directory. I can't get what you mean by "check whether your XPath fails (and Operadora is 're-used'), if so log the fact and don't rename the file."... I should use "nomeCerto = "IR21 - "& Operadora & ".xml"" with a full path?

Comment: I can't find a pattern to understand why it functions sometimes. It renamed some files, didn't rename some and represented the "Path not found" error, now

Comment: @CharlieVelez I think what Ekkehard.Horner is hinting at is this: when the XML file you're currently processing does not contain a node matching your XPath expression (`//OrganisationInfo/OrganisationName`) the variable `operadora` retains the value from the *previous* loop cycle. Because of that the `MoveFile` statement tries to overwrite the file you moved before and thus fails.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, would you please show me how would be your solution? I can't get what you mean by "check whether your XPath fails"... If i change "Operadora" value after the MoveFile, I wouldn't be denying this problem? I still can't see whats wrong :/

Comment: @CharlieVelez Your code says you don't do anything to prevent `operadora` from retaining its previous value when no new value is found. Try putting a line `WScript.Echo "_" & nomeErrado & "_" & vbNewLine & "_" & nomeCerto & "_"` before the `MoveFile` statement. What is its output when the error occurs?

Comment: I found 2 problems. You both were right, @Ekkehard.Horner and Asgar. Using the message box like Ekkehard told me to, i was able to see that some "Operadoras" have illegal material in its name("/"), what makes the file not able to be saved... This problem is solved, I will ask another question, for you have answered this one wonderfully. Thanks a lot! If you can help me, the link to my another question will be below!

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, here it is. Thanks, again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116094/rename-xml-files-with-vbscript-using-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Change your move file line to this;

```
FSO.moveFile nomeErrado & "/" & fil.Name, nomeErrado & "/" & nomeCerto
```

Comment: "nomeErrado" is the full path, so appending the file name again won't help.

Comment: Still the same problem... Path not found :/

Comment: try adding a wscript.echo to each of the path names to see if they are what you are expecting.